# CSS - Change column width of fixed table to accomodate longer text in one line

Tags: css

So I have a table with a navigation bar to scroll through the records. I changed the `table-layout` property to `fixed` so the columns wouldn't move when scrolling through the navigation. To do so, I had to apply the following CSS code:

```
table.fixed {
  table-layout:fixed;
}
table.fixed td {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is that one of the columns of the table (the third one in this case) isn't able to fit the whole text in one line breaking it in two lines. How can I change the width of the column in order to accommodate longer text into one line?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<td nowrap>
</td>
```

If you are using HTML 5 then

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap">
</td>
```